# Facebook CSharp Api using graph api to get other users feed, issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Im trying to get o other users feed in ASP.NET using Facebook CSharp API LIB, but with no sucess.

The results not cover all wall posts, only external posts to that came from other users to that user.

Here is piece of my code that call facebook graph api get :

```
  var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get(user.id + "/feed");
```

Might be something very simple that I couldn't figure out yet...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i see a problem here, the /feed connection approximately represents that user's wall - you should be able to see any posts on the user's wall which are visible to the user whose access token you're using - is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I discover that is the permission of app to "read_stream"